# Sorting by date with variable number of columns

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to sort lines consisting of dates, but I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to sort the lines and keep the lines whole. I also don't understand how to use pipe to sort the lines.

For example, my script receives this as a text file:

```
asdsa 24 asdsa 3 3000 054217542 30.3.2016
asdsadsa 25 asdsadsaa 5 4500 534215365 2.1.2014
dsasda 23 dsada 4 3200 537358234 6.3.2016
```

I would like to read line by line:

```
while read line; do

done < "$1"
```

And inside sort the lines by their dates. How can I sort the lines as a they are in a file, while I read them one by one?

What if I do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=${PATH[*]}:.
#filename: testScript


while read line; do
    arr=( $line )
    num_of_params=`echo ${#arr[*]}`
    echo $line | sort -n -k$num_of_params

    num_of_params=0
done < "$1"
```

My problem with this is that I actually send each line by its own to sort, and not the lines all together, but I don't know any other other way to do it (without using temp files, I'm not looking to use any of these).

Output:

```
asdsa 24 asdsa 3 3000 054217542 30.3.2016
asdsadsa 25 asdsadsaa 5 4500 534215365 2.1.2014
dsasda 23 dsada 4 3200 537358234 6.3.2016
```

Desired output:

```
asdsadsa 25 asdsadsaa 5 4500 534215365 2.1.2014
dsasda 23 dsada 4 3200 537358234 6.3.2016
asdsa 24 asdsa 3 3000 054217542 30.3.2016
```

As you can see, it didn't work.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Please desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus Done, added the output.

Comment: No, Cyrus asked for *desired* output. What do you expect the correct output to be?

Comment: @Mort Didn't read his sentence well for some odd reason. Added that as well!

Comment: I forgot an "add".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) with awk and `cut`:

```
awk '{split($NF,arr,"."); printf("%d%02d%02d\t%s\n",arr[3],arr[2],arr[1],$0)}' infile |
sort -k 1,1 | cut -f 2-
```

The awk part first splits the last field of the record, `$NF` (the date), at the periods into an array `arr`:

```
split($NF,arr,".")
```

The second part prints the line with the reformatted date prepended: first the year, then the month and the day, the latter two with zero padding to two digits:

```
printf("%d%02d%02d\t%s\n",arr[3],arr[2],arr[1],$0)
```

The output of this looks as follows:

```
20160330        asdsa 24 asdsa 3 3000 054217542 30.3.2016
20140102        asdsadsa 25 asdsadsaa 5 4500 534215365 2.1.2014
20160306        dsasda 23 dsada 4 3200 537358234 6.3.2016
```

Now we can just pipe to `sort` and use the first field:

```
sort -k 1,1
```

resulting in

```
20140102        asdsadsa 25 asdsadsaa 5 4500 534215365 2.1.2014
20160306        dsasda 23 dsada 4 3200 537358234 6.3.2016
20160330        asdsa 24 asdsa 3 3000 054217542 30.3.2016
```

And finally, we remove our inserted field again with `cut`, leaving only everything from the second field on:

```
cut -f 2-
```

resulting in

```
asdsadsa 25 asdsadsaa 5 4500 534215365 2.1.2014
dsasda 23 dsada 4 3200 537358234 6.3.2016
asdsa 24 asdsa 3 3000 054217542 30.3.2016
```

---

#### A Bash solution

If instead of awk we want to use just Bash, we can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read each line into an array 'line'
while read -r -a line; do

    # Find the number of array elements
    nel=${#line[@]}

    # Assign the last element of the array to 'date'
    date=${line[nel-1]}

    # Extract the month from the date with parameter expansion
    month=${date#*.}
    month=${month%.*}

    # Year and day need only one expansion step, which is done here directly
    printf "%d%02d%02d\t%s\n" "${date##*.}" "$month" "${date%%.*}" "${line[*]}"

# Pipe result to sort, then remove the first column with cut
done < infile | sort -k 1,1 | cut -f 2-
```

The general idea is exactly the same: we add an extra column containing the reformatted date, sort by that and then remove it again.

Comment: That's-.. brilliant.

Comment: I didn't fully understand how do we pipe the sort to the printf, though. And what if more than 3 lines are passed to the script? Will it still work?

Comment: We don't pipe the output of `sort` to `printf`. The file is completely processed by awk first, then piped to `sort` and sorted, then piped to `cut` where the first column gets removed again. The intermediate output is only shown for illustration, the actual output of the command is just the last one.

Comment: I'm not supposed to use awk. I created an array which has the fixed lines(the lines with these numbers at the begging) in it. For example, `arr[0] = 20140102        asdsadsa 25 asdsadsaa 5 4500 534215365 2.1.2014`, etc. I'm now looking to pipe that to sort. How do I do that please?

Comment: @LamaEu I've added a Bash solution.

Comment: I really do owe my degree to Stack Overflow

Comment: One LAST question. `printf "%d%02d%02d\t%s\n" "${date##*.}" "$month" "${date%%.*}" "${line[*]}"` prints the line? What does it do? Will it print the line, then pipe it to sort and then cut, and only then display it? But what it does, is basically just print the line as is? I mean, will the output of this, set aside the pipes, be: `20140102 asdsadsa 25 asdsadsaa 5 4500 534215365 2.1.2014` ?

Comment: @LamaEu It prints the formatted line. Piping to sort happens outside of the `while .. done` loop; because the output of the whole loop is piped, first to `sort`, then to `cut`, printing to stdout happens only after all the transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
awk -F"[\. ]*" '
{
   printf "%d%02d%02d %s\n", $NF, $(NF-1), $(NF-2), $0
}' test | sort -n | cut -c10-
```

`test` is the  name of your file of course... It depends on the date being the last part of each line in the format you've specified in your initial post. (Tested on FreeBSD with (n)awk)