# Reading the output of a script in a particular way

Tags: bash, shell, unix

So I have a script called `sortByDates`. As you may have guessed, it sorts by dates.
I would like to send a bunch of lines to it(stored in an array in my main script) and read the lines `sortByDates` returns.
Something like this. Say I have:

```
One 26 One 4 4000 0575342 18.3.2016
Two 27 Two 3 3100 0599342 24.3.2016
Three 28 Three 2 2950 0556742 4.3.2016
Four 29 Four 3 3150 0562342 2.4.2016
```

Those lines are stored as:

```
arr[0]=One 26 One 4 4000 0575342 18.3.2016
arr[1]=Two 27 Two 3 3100 0599342 24.3.2016
arr[2]=Three 28 Three 2 2950 0556742 4.3.2016
arr[3]=Four 29 Four 3 3150 0562342 2.4.2016
```

I would like to send these lines to `sortByDates`, by something like:

```
$(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | sortByDates
```

This what I would have usually be doing, but I want this to be implented a bit different. Something like:

```
while read -r line; do
    sortedLines+=("$line")
done < <(sortByDates < $(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"))
```

And that's where I stumble. The code above does not work. I fail to understand how to redirect a bunch of lines(or an array) to another script, while I read the new lines(the script's output) to a new array, called `sortedLines`.
The output should look this way:

```
Three 28 Three 2 2950 0556742 4.3.2016
One 26 One 4 4000 0575342 18.3.2016
Two 27 Two 3 3100 0599342 24.3.2016
Four 29 Four 3 3150 0562342 2.4.2016
```

So I want `sortedLines` to be:

```
sortedLines[0]=Three 28 Three 2 2950 0556742 4.3.2016
sortedLines[1]=One 26 One 4 4000 0575342 18.3.2016
sortedLines[2]=Two 27 Two 3 3100 0599342 24.3.2016
sortedLines[3]=Four 29 Four 3 3150 0562342 2.4.2016
```

Thank you.

Comment: I have a déjà vu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368188/sorting-by-date-with-variable-number-of-columns/37368527#37368527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sortedLines=()
while read -r line; do
    sortedLines+=("$line")
done < <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | sortByDates)
printf "%s\n" "${sortedLines[@]}"
```

This produces the output:

```
Three 28 Three 2 2950 0556742 4.3.2016
One 26 One 4 4000 0575342 18.3.2016
Two 27 Two 3 3100 0599342 24.3.2016
Four 29 Four 3 3150 0562342 2.4.2016
```

The uses *process substitution* to feed the results of `` to the `while` loop.

Aside: The command `sortByDates < $(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}")` tells the shell to provide as input to `sortByDates` the contents of a file named `$(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"`.  That is note what you want.

#### Debugging

Try running the script under `bash -x`.  Alternatively, try this script:

```
sortedLines=()
while read -r line; do
    echo line=$line
    sortedLines+=("$line")
    declare -p sortedLines
done < <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | sortByDates)
declare -p sortedLines
```

For me, the above produces:

```
line=Three 28 Three 2 2950 0556742 4.3.2016
declare -a sortedLines='([0]="Three 28 Three 2 2950 0556742 4.3.2016")'
line=One 26 One 4 4000 0575342 18.3.2016
declare -a sortedLines='([0]="Three 28 Three 2 2950 0556742 4.3.2016" [1]="One 26 One 4 4000 0575342 18.3.2016")'
line=Two 27 Two 3 3100 0599342 24.3.2016
declare -a sortedLines='([0]="Three 28 Three 2 2950 0556742 4.3.2016" [1]="One 26 One 4 4000 0575342 18.3.2016" [2]="Two 27 Two 3 3100 0599342 24.3.2016")'
line=Four 29 Four 3 3150 0562342 2.4.2016
declare -a sortedLines='([0]="Three 28 Three 2 2950 0556742 4.3.2016" [1]="One 26 One 4 4000 0575342 18.3.2016" [2]="Two 27 Two 3 3100 0599342 24.3.2016" [3]="Four 29 Four 3 3150 0562342 2.4.2016")'
declare -a sortedLines='([0]="Three 28 Three 2 2950 0556742 4.3.2016" [1]="One 26 One 4 4000 0575342 18.3.2016" [2]="Two 27 Two 3 3100 0599342 24.3.2016" [3]="Four 29 Four 3 3150 0562342 2.4.2016")'
```

Comment: Doesn't work :/ Prints nothing, when I do: `printf "%s\n" "${sortedLines[@]}"`

Comment: It works fine for me.  Please see the debugging section that I just added.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Turns out I had an error in the previous array. Much appreciated, John :)

Comment: Sorry for the trouble :)